# Python -- execfile function

Tags: python

Consider the contents of my file "sandbox.py":

```
execfile('sandbox.py')
```

When I ran it, it threw a huge, repetitive error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    execfile('sandbox.py')
#(.... Same thing for about a 1000 more times...)
KeyError: 'unknown symbol table entry'
```

In summary, could anyone explain what just happened? Why is an error related to dictionaries popping up when I use execfile and nothing else?

Comment: Yeah... why are you calling yourself infinitely? What you did was akin to making a recursive call without a terminal case.

Comment: I'm just curious how python would handle this. I recall that python somehow allows circular imports in some cases.

Comment: Okay... but circular imports and exec'ing a process are completely different concepts.

Comment: If this could be compared to a function calling itself infinitely, would I still get the "KeyError"?

Comment: @NageshEranki who knows? This is unexpected behavior to begin with, you're lucky it didn't just freeze your computer and threw any error at all instead

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613489/limit-on-symbol-table